# xargs with multiple commands only working on some files

Tags: bash, macos, xargs

I'm trying (starting with my Macbook) to get a list of all image files matching the specification in the line below along with their size and sha512. I'm doing this to audit the tens of thousands of such files I have spread over mutliple systems.

```
sudo find /Users \( -iname '*.JPG' -or -iname '*.NEF' -or -iname '*.PNG'
-or -iname '*.RAF' -or -iname '*.PW2' -or -iname '*.DNG' \) -type f -and 
-size +10000k -print0 | xargs -0 -I @@ 
/bin/bash -c '{ stat -n -f"MACBOOK %z " "@@" && shasum -p -a 512 "@@"; }'
```

When run, this correctly produces the output I want for some of the files, for example I get;

```
MACBOOK 32465640 <SHA512-REDACTED> ?/Users/<REDACTED>/Pictures/Pendleton Roundup/2018/2018-09-13/_DSC3955.NEF
```

But for some of the files, the @@ replacement doesn't seem to work properly and instead I get;

```
MACBOOK 28130793 shasum: @@:
```

If I add a -v flag to the bash line to print out the commands I expect to be executed when it goes wrong I see this;

```
{ stat -n -f"MACBOOK %z " "/Users/<REDACTED>/Pictures/Photos Library D750.photoslibrary/Masters/2018/07/29/20180729-223141/DSC_3274.NEF"; shasum -p -a 512 "@@"; }
```

If I manually run that line with the @@ replaced with the filename, it works as expected, so it seems that the -I @@ parameter to xargs is somehow not always working and I'm at a loss as to what the cause might me.

Can anyone help me evolve a fix for this? I've tried putting the @@ in quotes, tried with different patterns and always the same issue.

Comment: Why the Linux tag? OS X is most similar to the BSDs, not Linux. You have to use BSD flavor of the commands, not Linux flavor. (OS X and BSDs manage to do things even more anemic than Posix at times).

Comment: I tagged it as linux because I need to perform this across multiple systems, some of those systems are macos based, some of them are closer to ubuntu, and for my sins some of them are windows based and I will probably use cygwin or just mount the volumes on a linux system. Once I have something that works on macos, I stand a fighting chance of migrating it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
find_args=( -false )
for type in jpg nef png raf pw2 dng; do
  find_args+=( -o -name "*.$type" )
done

sudo find /Users '(' "${find_args[@]}" ')' \
  -type f \
  -size +10000k \
  -exec sh -c '
    for arg; do
      stat -n -f"MACBOOK %z " "$arg"
      shasum -p -a 512 "$arg"
    done' _ {} +
```

Using `-exec ... {} +` lets `find` invoke only one copy of `sh` per batch of files (as many as will fit on a command line on your local platform).

Even more importantly, not using `{}` inside the `sh -c` argument avoids command injection vulnerabilities, which with the original code would allow malicious filenames to run arbitrary commands (especially important when you're running under `sudo`, so those commands would be executed as root!).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that you were using xargs. It's that your `find` was run with sudo but any process receiving your piped or redirected output was *not* run with sudo, so your permissions during the `find` do not match your permissions during the subsequent `xargs` execution.

So, for example, instead of running:

```
sudo ls -al >> list.txt
```

you should instead run the entire pipeline of commands with sudo, as follows:

```
sudo sh -c 'ls -al >> list.txt'
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) comes immediately to mind.

Comment: Sure, but it was just a simple example of how to apply sudo to an entire pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: NOT RECOMMENDED - see comment below.

I seem to have a variant that works now without xargs.

```
sudo find /Users \( -iname '*.JPG' -or -iname '*.NEF' -or -iname '*.PNG' -or -iname '*.RAF'
-or -iname '*.PW2' -or -iname '*.DNG' \) -type f -and -size +10000k
-exec sh -c '{ stat -n -f"MACBOOK %z " "{}"; shasum -p -a 512 "{}"; }' {} \;
```

Comment: Don't *ever* put `{}` inside the argument that immediately follows `sh -c`; that lends itself to command injection vulnerabilities. Look at what happens when someone runs `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'.png'` inside a directory your command covers.

Comment: Thanks - in this particular case I'd personally be OK as I have physical control over who executes what and where, but I had missed that as I wasn't considering command injection when I was trying to get it to work. Good advice !!